# Can't link movie with a genre_id in form for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select

I'm trying to link movies with a specific genre via a form in rails.  I have seeded several genre instances in the db and have created a select tag that should, in theory, give a movie a genre_id based on the genres seeded.

Here is my Movie Migration:

```
class CreateMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :movies do |t|
     t.string :name
      t.integer :year
      t.string :director
      t.string :lead_actor
      t.references :genre, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the form:

```
<%= form_for(@movie) do |f| %>
  <% if @movie.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@movie.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this movie from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @movie.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :genre_id %><br>
    <%= f.select(:genre_id, @genres.map {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :year %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :year %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :director %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :director %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lead_actor %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :lead_actor %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

All of my dropdown boxes are being displayed properly, but when I go into the database and check the movies genre_id, it equals 'nil'.

Full controller:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_movie, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /movies
  # GET /movies.json
  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
  end

  # GET /movies/1
  # GET /movies/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /movies/new
  def new
    @movie = Movie.new
    @genres = Genre.all
  end

  # GET /movies/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /movies
  # POST /movies.json
  def create
    @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @movie.save
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @movie }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /movies/1
  # PATCH/PUT /movies/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @movie.update(movie_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @movie }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /movies/1
  # DELETE /movies/1.json
  def destroy
    @movie.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to movies_url, notice: 'Movie was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_movie
      @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def movie_params
      params.require(:movie).permit(:name, :year, :director, :lead_actor)
    end
end
```

Comment: Are you saying that the app runs fine, but when you use the rails console to check on it, it shows `nil`?

Comment: Can you post you full controller?

Comment: the app runs fine, but it the movie is not being saved with a genre_id... denys281 just posted the controller

Comment: Just figured it out.... params.require(:movie).permit(:name, :year, :director, :lead_actor) in controller needs :genre_id